# Summing all values with same ID in a column give me duplicated values in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to sum all the columns that have the same ID number in a specified date range, but it always gives me duplicated values

```
select pr.product_sku,
       pr.product_name, 
       pr.brand,
       pr.category_name,
       pr.subcategory_name,
       a.stock_on_hand, 
       sum(pr.pageviews) as page_views,
       sum(acquired_subscriptions) as acquired_subs,
       sum(acquired_subscription_value) as asv_value
from dwh.product_reporting pr
join dm_product.product_data_livefeed a 
on pr.product_sku = a.product_sku 
where pr.fact_day between '2022-05-01' and '2022-05-30' and pr.pageviews > '0' and pr.acquired_subscription_value > '0'  and store_id = 1 
group by pr.product_sku,
         pr.product_name,
         pr.brand,
         pr.category_name,
         pr.subcategory_name,
         a.stock_on_hand;
```

This supposes to give me:
Sum of all KPI values for a distinct product SKU
Example table:

```
|     Date   | product_sku |page_views|number_of_subs
|------------|-------------|----------|--------------|
| 2022-01-01 |     1       |   110    |    50        |
| 2022-01-25 |     2       |   1000   |    40        |
| 2022-01-20 |     3       |   2000   |    10        |
| 2022-01-01 |     1       |   110    |    50        |
| 2022-01-25 |     2       |   1000   |    40        |
| 2022-01-20 |     3       |   2000   |    10        |
```

Expected Output:

```
| product_sku |page_views|number_of_subs
|-------------|----------|--------------|
|     1       |   220    |    100       |
|     2       |   2000   |    80        |
|     3       |   4000   |    20        |
```

Sorry I had to edit to add the table examples

Comment: Which of your `group by` columns is not unique for product_sku?

Comment: Sql server <> mysql. Don't spam-tag products not involved

Comment: What is `KPI`? What is `SKU`?

Comment: a.stock_on_hand is the only thing that may vary

Comment: KPI means column names, and SKU is an ID

Comment: "KPI means column names"? "SKU is an ID"? This might seem meaningful to you, but we don't know anything about your database. Show us your tables, sample data and expected (and actual) output

Comment: Also, why are you comparing `pr.pageviews` to a string? It seems likely it's an integer. Likewise for `pr.acquired_subscription_value`

Comment: product sku = product serial number for example product name x has a product sku : XY123XY

Comment: I don't want to compare them I want all the page views and other summed values for product x

Comment: Just curious.  If you take out the a.stock_on_hand,  and the JOIN  ... Is that closer to what you expect ?

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) your schema, sample data, and your actual (showing the duplicated values) and desired results for that sample data

Comment: I added table example hopefully that makes it clearer

Comment: This is a simple aggregation.   If you are getting "dupes" then I suspect the JOIN or Control Characters in the SKU.   As this demonstrates, the data works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6f2680baa69a09fc258260948d7d9969

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not listing the dupes (assuming they are truly appearing as *duplicate* rows, and not just multiple rows with different values), I'll offer that there may be something else that's at play here - I would suggest for every string value in your result set that's part of the GROUP BY clause to apply a TRIM(UPPER())  as you might be dealing with either a case insensitivity or trailing blanks that are treated as unique values in the query.

Assuming all the columns are character based:

```
select trim(upper(pr.product_sku)),
       trim(upper(pr.product_name)), 
       trim(upper(pr.brand)),
       trim(upper(pr.category_name)),
       trim(upper(pr.subcategory_name)),
       sum(pr.pageviews) as page_views,
       sum(acquired_subscriptions) as acquired_subs,
       sum(acquired_subscription_value) as asv_value
from dwh.product_reporting pr
where pr.fact_day between '2022-05-01' and '2022-05-30' and pr.pageviews > '0' and pr.acquired_subscription_value > '0'  and store_id = 1 
group by trim(upper(pr.product_sku)),
       trim(upper(pr.product_name)), 
       trim(upper(pr.brand)),
       trim(upper(pr.category_name)),
       trim(upper(pr.subcategory_name));
```

Comment: I added table example hopefully that makes it clearer

Comment: The table and the results are a subset of the information shown in the query.  Please list some sample results of the duplicates you're seeing.  At a glance, with everything else equal, I suspect you're not seeing true duplicates.  I would run this without the join to dm_product.product_data_livefeed a  and see if you still have duplicates returned.

Comment: I see above you removed the join and got the same results.  For your duplicate rows, do *all* the columns returned contain the same values (at least from visual inspection)?

Comment: Does the query I added to my answer above resolve the issue?  If not, please post examples of your duplicate results (all columns and values please)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all your help, I found out where the problem was. It was mainly in the `group by` when I removed all the other column names and left only the product_sku column, it worked as required